# Where can I find a WMS map to overlay on tableau that shows sea-level rise (globally preferably)

Tags: wms, service-recommendations, tableau

I am trying to overlay a WMS sea level rise map over my data on tableau but I am having no luck in finding one. I have found a few good interactive sea-level rise maps (https://coastal.climatecentral.org/map/10/12.7992/55.6273/ and https://sealevel.nasa.gov/ipcc-ar6-sea-level-projection-tool) but I am not sure how to overlay these on tableau using the WMS background map feature.

Comment: Hello, welcome to GIS SE. You mention you have the WMS map and intend to use tableau (Tableau BI ?) WMS map feature: please share more details on the map source you found and where you are with your attempts in Tableau. This will make it much easier to provide some help

Comment: Can you give examples of the interactive sea-level rise maps that you have found

Comment: If it’s an open data service that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the responses. The interactive maps I found are : https://coastal.climatecentral.org/map/10/12.7992/55.6273/? and https://sealevel.nasa.gov/ipcc-ar6-sea-level-projection-tool.

Comment: And with regards to my progress in tableau, I have made a map of all our companys clients around the world. And the plan was to overlay different climate risk scenarios over that such as se-level rise, drought or heat waves etc. Other suggestions for alternative methods would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The two example of interactive maps you give do not expose the data as a WMS, so you won't be able to incorporate into Tableau using WMS tools directly; you could though download the data (https://sealevel.nasa.gov/data/data-search? and https://go.climatecentral.org/coastaldem/?utm_campaign=coastal_tool&utm_content=CoastalDEM-button) and configure your own WMS.